# ZXING to encode and save image

Tags: android, zxing

I know there are a lot of threads about ZXing so apologies for adding to the heap. I'm using intents to open up the barcode scanner app to scan a QRCode. I did this with the IntentIntegrator class written by the same guys.

I know you can use intents to generate a QRCode as well, but how would you go about saving that image to your assets folder? I can create the code via intent, but how do I save that image?

Apologies if this has been covered, but I couldn't find an example anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the app's encode screen, the user can press menu and choose Share to send it or do whatever else the user wants with it. If you want to programmatically retrieve that image, no, you can't do that. But for that, you just want to actually embed the encoding code in your app. (remember the Apache License terms of course.)

Comment: Thanks for replying Sean. Guess I'll have to go the long route of embedding the encoding.